# How to make this type of wallpaper?

Tags: android

I am beginner of Android OpenGL I want to learn and make Live wallpaper Like image please
   anyone give me some link or tutorial for learn and making this type of Apps.[image]

Comment: http://bit.ly/z6XDTv leads to http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html Sigh, is this so hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/index.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html

Comment: execuse me for bad explanation of question I have done one openGL live wallpaper but I want to ask how to draw rndering fire flame in open GL please help me anyone...

Comment: Oh I see, fire flame like the one above? 

Try looking around here, im sure they have something useful, im not really with the whole openGL thing yet so yeah sorry I cant help more